# Translation .po file is not called

Tags: php, wordpress, localization, internationalization

#### I can't translate my wordpress plugin.

I have my `.po` and `.mo` files inside the `plugin-name/languages` folder but it doesn't work. Does anyone have a clue on what could be missing?

---

#### Details:

I translated the theme using the .po and .mo files and adding `define('WPLANG', 'pt_BR');` on `wp-config.php`. It works fine.

But not all website is translated. So I tried the same with the plugins, but even translating the plugin .pot and naming `plugin-name-pt_BR.po` and `plugin-name-pt_BR.mo`, and placing them on `/plugin-name/languages` (which already existed) as I saw on the internet, it didn't work.

I also tried copying the translations on `plugin-name-pt_BR.po` and pasting inside `wp-content/themes/theme-name/languages/pt_BR.po`, but it was not use.

I tried installing `Loco-Translate` and `POEditor`, but they only manage the .po translation, which is fine and translated, but not reflected on the website.

I don't know much of Wordpress and PHP, but it seems to me that the plugin code might lack something to call the .po file.

If I don't translate this way, I'll have to translate directly inside the plugin's source code.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. It's a little unclear what you are asking. Give this article a read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask as it'll give you some pointers on how to correctly ask questions in order to get good quality answers. Remember always to provide complete, minimal and verifiable examples to let others assist you

Comment: Thank you @JavierLarroulet. I'm sorry, I tried to provide the steps I took so it could be easier understood as I saw in another tutorial. I'll rewrite it.

Comment: @brenorb, have you added `load_theme_textdomain` function in the functions.php of your theme?

Comment: @IvnH the theme came prepared for it. The function `load_theme_textdomain( 'theme', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );` is inside the theme setup function. Also, It translates almost everything.

Maybe it's a conflict inside the .po file... I don't know...

Comment: I just saw this guy had the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40438335/wordpress-cant-translate-one-term-with-loco-translate-plugin) but I didn't understand the solution. Did he just did the same thing again and it worked?

Comment: gettext can be weird in apache, try restarting the service or have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13625659/how-to-clear-phps-gettext-cache-without-restart-apache-nor-change-domain)

Comment: @brenorb, do you uploaded mo file same as po?

Comment: @IvnH Yes, I did, compiled from the po file in Poedit.

Comment: @brenorb, have you tried to re-sync translation? This options is in Poedit same as in Loco translate.

Comment: @IvnH What is re-sync translation? I don't have Poedit paid version, maybe that's not available. I didn't see this option in Loco Translate. 
Actually, what I did is commenting the original phrases and manually translated directly on the code. I know it's bad, but it was the only way to work now :/

Comment: @brenorb In Poedit try from menu Catalogue - Update from sources